# Consolidating rows into regions in data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have some data that's neatly arranged in an R data frame that looks like this:

```
chr    from    to    value
  1     101   200     0.17
  1     201   300     0.18
  1     301   400     0.17
  1     801   900     0.34
  1     901  1000     0.37
  1    1001  1100     0.36
  2     501   600     0.22
  2     601   700     0.23
  2    1501  1600     0.11
  2    1601  1700     0.13
```

What I would like to do is consolidate the lowest number in the `from` column with the greatest number in the `to` column but only for contiguous regions within each chromosome, and then take the average of the `value` field. So for example, the output should look like this:

```
chr    from    to    value
  1     101   400    0.173
  1     801  1100    0.357
  2     501   700    0.225
  2    1501  1700    0.12
```

I was wondering if anyone had some thoughts as to how this could be done in R or if there's any package out there that might be able to help me with this kind of thing.

Comment: Why has your example result got 4 rows rather than 2 (as there are 2 levels of 'chr')?

Comment: This was because with in each "chr" region there were two different contiguous regions that needed to be concatenated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`).  Grouped by 'chr', we create a new column ('ind') based on the difference in current value of 'to' with next value of 'from', check which element is not equal to 1, pad with `TRUE` to get the lengths same, and `cumsum`.  Using the 'ind', and 'chr' as grouping variables, we get the first value of 'from' (`from[1L]`), last of 'to' (`to[.N]`), and the `mean` of 'value' column.  If needed, we can remove the 'ind' by assigning to 'NULL'.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
setDT(df1)[, ind:=cumsum(c(TRUE,(from[-1L]-to[-.N])!=1)), by = chr]
df1[,list(from=from[1L], to=to[.N], value=mean(value))
      ,.(ind, chr)][, ind:= NULL][]
#   chr from   to     value
#1:   1  101  400 0.1733333
#2:   1  801 1100 0.3566667
#3:   2  501  700 0.2250000
#4:   2 1501 1700 0.1200000
```

Or this can be done in a slghtly more compact way by grouping directly with the `cumsum(...)` along with 'chr' and then get the first value of 'from', last of 'to', and the `mean` of 'value'.  We used `shift` to get the lag of 'to' column (by default the `type='lag'` in `shift`) and compare with 'from' to get the logical vector and did the cumulative sum (`cumsum`)

```
setDT(df1)[,list(from=from[1L], to=to[.N], value=mean(value)) 
   ,.(V1=cumsum(from!=shift(to, fill=TRUE)+1L), chr)][, V1:=NULL][]
```

---

A similar option using `dplyr` would be

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(V1=cumsum(from!=lag(to, default=TRUE)+1L), chr) %>%
    summarise(from=first(from), to=last(to), value=mean(value)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-V1)
#    chr  from    to     value
#   (int) (int) (int)     (dbl)
#1     1   101   400 0.1733333
#2     1   801  1100 0.3566667
#3     2   501   700 0.2250000
#4     2  1501  1700 0.1200000
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(chr = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), from = c(101L, 201L, 301L, 801L, 901L, 1001L, 501L, 601L, 
1501L, 1601L), to = c(200L, 300L, 400L, 900L, 1000L, 1100L, 600L, 
700L, 1600L, 1700L), value = c(0.17, 0.18, 0.17, 0.34, 0.37, 
0.36, 0.22, 0.23, 0.11, 0.13)), .Names = c("chr", "from", "to", 
"value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Thank you all for your quick response. These are all great solutions. I ended up implementing the dplyr code but these all worked great for my problem.

Comment: @Steven Thank you for the feedback.  Glad that it works for you.